# React Native - Unsubscribe subscription in Apollo Client

Tags: react-native, apollo, apollo-client

I got that error every time I open the app again after being close for more than 3 minutes. Any idea of what's the problem? Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const observer = client.subscribe({
      query: SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_FOR_FORUM,
      variables: {roomId: currRoom.id},
    });

    const subscription = observer.subscribe(({data}) => {
      console.log('SUBSCRIBE received', data);
      if (data) {
        const newTopicId = data.createTopicForForum.topicId;
        const exists = topics.find(({topicId}) => topicId === newTopicId);
        if (!exists) {
          setTopics(arr => [data.createTopicForForum].concat(arr));
        }
      }
    });

    console.log('subscription: ', subscription);

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [currRoom.id]);
```

[image]

[image]